# How does the "shuffle back" mechanic work?

Tags: steamworld-quest

Every turn you can "shuffle back" (or mulligan) up to 2 cards from your hands to your deck and draw another card for each. Actually, it put them aside, which means you won't see it again, before *every other card* is seen.

Since in Steamworld quest you've got a party of 3 with 8 cards each, I was wondering if the shuffle count *only* the character who is shuffling (1 in 8 you won't see for a while) or all the team (1 in 24).

Comment: I don't believe characters shuffle cards.  You, as the player, do.  So I'm not sure what you're trying to get at.

Comment: @Frank You as a player, choose a character-related card to shuffle. Your total deck size is 24 cards, but it's not specified if you shuffle a Armille card, you've got to see every other of *her* cards before redrawing it, or if you need to see all of the other cards. The discard is hidden in this game, hence the question.